# Why do we use present progressive in this case?

Tags: progressive-aspect, stative-verbs

We learned that present progressive form is not available when related to the human emotion we have.
But I can see the example using 'present progressive' in the sentence.
for example, 'I am still loving you.' or ' I am lovin' it'
What is the reason why we can use the present progressive form in the sentence?
Please, tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That a stative verb cannot be used with a progressive aspect is a huge myth. According to The Teacher's Grammar of English, we can use the form *stative progressive* to make the statement sound more emotional, intense, and vivid.